# Displaying latex on mobile

Tags: support

Is there a way to compile the math formulas in the stack exchange app for iphone ? It is quite boring (and hard) to translate on the go.

Sorry if my question was obvious but i didnt find anything. Sorry also for te tag but didnt find anything good. Feel free to edit.

Comment: Write enough $\rm\LaTeX$, and you can compile the formulas in your head on the fly.

Comment: This is marked as [meta-tag:status-completed] on meta.SE: [MathJax doesn't render in the iOS app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288315). (The post said it should be fixed in 1.6.3.) You can probably find a few related questions if you look at questions tagged both (mathjax) and (ios-app) on [meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathjax+ios-app) or on [meta.math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathjax+ios-app).